# How does Android prevent apps from getting permissions which are not assigned to them?

Tags: android, android-permissions

•   How does it work internally?

•   If the app does not have access to the permission, i.e: the GIDs are not associated with this app process then the process does not get the permission.

•   Eg: INTERNET permission. Say the developer forgot to mention this permission in the Android Manifest file.Therefore, what happens next when the process tries to communicate with the internet??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the help. I looked into it and it seems I should read in the underlying linux architecture to better understand how this works.

Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

They use Lint to scan the project and prevent bugs.

Check [this](http://tools.android.com/tips/lint)

Hope this help.